# While код не работает

Tags: javascript

```js
var alphabet = "абвгдеежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
var randomString = "";
while (randomString < 6) {
  randomString = randomString + alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
}
console.log(randomString);
```

Я пытаюсь сделать код, который будет возвращать три рандомные буквы из алфавита одной строкой (randomString). Но при запуске кода, он возвращает только одну букву, вместо трех. Что то не так в While?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var alphabet = "абвгдеежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
var randomString = "";
while (randomString.length < 3) {
  randomString = randomString + alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
}
console.log(randomString);
```

Вы не смотрите длину строки. обратитесь к полю/свойству `length`.